# Buffer group by groups with Reactive Extensions, nested subscribe

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive

I have an event source that generates events that belong to certain groups. I would like to buffer these groups and send the groups (in batches) to storage. So far I have this:

```
eventSource
    .GroupBy(event => event.GroupingKey)
    .Select(group => new { group.Key, Events = group })
    .Subscribe(group => group.Events
                            .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 100)
                            .Subscribe(list => SendToStorage(list)));
```

So there's a nested subscribe to the events in a group. Somehow I think there's a better way but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
eventSource
    .GroupBy(e => e.GroupingKey)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 100))
    .Subscribe(list => SendToStorage(list));
```

Here's a couple general rules that can help you 'reduce':

1) A nested subscription is normally fixed with `Select`ing everything before the nested subscription followed by a `Merge`, then followed by the nested subscription. So applying that, you get this:

```
eventSource
    .GroupBy(e => e.GroupingKey)
    .Select(group => new { group.Key, Events = group })
    .Select(group => group.Events.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 100)) //outer subscription selector
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(list => SendToStorage(list));
```

2) You can obviously combine two consecutive selects (and since you're not doing anything with the anonymous object, can just remove that):

```
eventSource
    .GroupBy(e => e.GroupingKey)
    .Select(group => group.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 100)) 
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(list => SendToStorage(list));
```

3) Finally, a `Select` followed by a `Merge` can be reduced to a `SelectMany`:

```
eventSource
    .GroupBy(e => e.GroupingKey)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 100))
    .Subscribe(list => SendToStorage(list));
```

Comment: Wrote some unit tests to verify it kept working and works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it

```
(from g in eventSource.GroupByUntil(e => e.GroupingKey,
                                    g => g.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 100))
 from b in g.ToList()
 select b).Subscribe(SendToStorage);
```